# How can I disable double border on every TouchableOpacity?

Tags: css, react-native

I'm making an React Native App in which i have 2 buttons/ TouchableOpacity's. When styling these buttons, they both get double border even when explicitly stating 'solid' borderstyle in the respective stylesheets. ( On the attached screenshot the middle button is all white, but when I make the border a different color it is a double one as well ). No where in the whole file have I defined a double borderstyle.

bottom left button stylesheet:

```
  roomsbutton: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#009DDC',
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderColor: 'white',
    color: 'white',
  }
```

and its parent view:

```
<View style={styles.bottom}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
      style={styles.roomsbutton}
      onPress={() => Alert.alert('more rooms')}
      >
        <Text style={styles.roomsbutton} >FIND MORE FREE ROOMS</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

[image: The bottom left button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the styles to the `<TouchableOpacity>` and the `<Text>` components. So they are both surrounded by the border

Answer (score 1):

You pass `style={styles.roomsbutton}` to both the `TouchableOpacity` *and* the `Text` components. Each have a solid white border

Answer (score 1):

this is happining because you apply className `.roomsbutton` two times in a button. once in `TouchableOpacity` and once in `Text`.

just remove `style={styles.roomsbutton}` form `Text` like below..

```
<Text>FIND MORE FREE ROOMS</Text>
```